# How do I create an executable in Visual Studio without linking to any libraries?

Tags: visual-c++, dynamic-linking, static-linking, libc

I'm attempting to make test case executables for a disassembler, and I'd like to strip off the bulk that linking to libc or libstdc++, etc. adds to an executable. This is all well and simple using GCC, and I've got plenty of samples from GCC with no libc dependence.

What I need is a compiled version of nothing more than

`void _start()
{
  return;
}`

After that, creating new examples should be pretty simple.

Just to note, I did scan through the cli options of cl.exe and saw nothing about not linking any libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that `/NODEFAULTLIB` on the command line will do what you want.

Comment: After tinkering around with your suggestion, the following is what has to be done: `cl file.c /link /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:_start /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` I still have to disassemble to see if it's as bare-bones as say a gcc bare app is.